# program is not reading the for loop

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.text.*;

public class Problem4 {

    public static int reverse( int n ) {
        int i = 0;

        while ( n != 0 ) {
            int r = n % 10;
            i = (i * 10) + r;
            n /= 10;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome( int n ) {
        return ( n == reverse(n) ) ? true : false;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int jHi=0, jlow=0, dec=0;
        int P=1;
        int i=999, j=1;

        for ( i=999; i <= 100; i = i - 1 )
        {
            if ( i % 11 == 0 )
            {    
                jHi = 999;
                jlow = 100;
                dec = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                jHi = 990;
                jlow = 100;
                dec = 11;
            }

            for ( j = jHi; j >= jlow; j = j - dec )
            {    
                P = i * j;

                if ( isPalindrome(P) )
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            } 
        }

        System.out.println( "Largest Palindrome is " + P );
    }
}
```

Comment: your sentinel value i <= 100 is never reached if you start out with i = 999

Comment: You might want to think about fine-tuning your editing environment. Wild, mismatching indents mixing spaces and tabs, inconsistent space padding etc. all conspire to make reading your code needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Your `for` loop does not execute because the loop condition `i<=100` is never met with an initial value of `i=999`.

Since you want your loop to count downwards, change

```
for(i=999; i<=100; i=i-1)
```

to

```
for(i=999; i>=100; i=i-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i=999; i<=100; i=i-1  --change it as i=999; i>=100; i=i-1

Answer (score 0):

This means "start with `i` as 999 and do it while `i` is less or equal than 100 decreasing `i` by one in each step":

```
for(i=999; i<=100; i=i-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop will not execute for very first time and hence no operation. Always use proper condition.